# Why do PhDs from a same university and potent subjects produce different outcomes?

Tags: phd, career-path

This question has been bugging me for a long time.

I don't know how to put it according to Academia.SE 's prescribed standard. Kindly help me to formulate this question by editing my question if you find it not conforming to the standards.

---

I know a Pakistani guy who has a Ph.D. in leadership from the University of Malaya and working as a clinical assistant professor at the University of Illinois and adviser to the PM.

I know a Bangladeshi girl, who completed Ph.D. in accounting from the same university and now working as a professor in a Malaysian privately funded university.

I know a Bangladeshi guy who completed a Ph.D. in IT from the same university and now working as the head of the computer center in a Bangladeshi university because of the political lobbying and backing of his father.

I know an Indian guy who completed Ph.D. in physics from the same University, and now working as a private tutor online.

In my opinion, the latter two are failures. Coz, they have failed to make proper use of their PhDs.

My question is **if the latter two are not as competent as the 1st and 2nd one, how did they manage to acquire a Ph.D.?**

N.B. kindly feel free to comment if you want to know more about these persons.

Comment: Why are the latter two failures? Why are they “not as much competent” (sic)? Most people who get a PhD end up not working in an academic role. Whether they’ve failed depends rather on what they set out to do. Just because you think they are failures doesn’t mean that they are.

Comment: Sorry but the "potent" really made me laugh, I wouldn't associate that adjective with a subject.

Comment: @HermanToothrot, potent means more job opportunity. Some subjects like History and Philosophy are less potent.

Comment: @user366312 That's not a typical use of the word in English, even if that's the meaning you intended.

Comment: Perhaps you mean you would think you failed if all you can get is a tutoring job.  That would be fine.  As the question is written, you are insulting tutors everywhere, which is probably not you intention.

Comment: @TerryLoring, Coz, they have failed to make proper use of their PhDs

Answer (score 7):

In most universities, what you must demonstrate to obtain a PhD is that you have made a novel contribution to knowledge in your field of study. Specifically at my university the requirement is worded as:

> A candidate for the degree of PhD, PhD with Integrated Studies, MD, DDSc, DMedSci,
> EdD, DEdCPsy, DClinPsy or EngD is required to satisfy the examiners that his or her
> thesis:
>
> - Is original work which forms an addition to knowledge
> - Shows evidence of systematic study and of the ability to relate the results of such
>   study to the general body of knowledge in the subject
> - Is worthy of publication either in full or in an abridged form

All of you above examples could easily have demonstrated the above. I'm assuming you believe that individual who works as a private tutor is the least successful of the four (this is only true if this is not the life they wish for themselves, many might see this as a nice life). Do you have any reason to suspect that this individual is not capable of making a novel contribution to knowledge? But passing this bar does not mean you will be a good government advisor, or professor.

The larger point is that PhDs are not tools for ranking people.  People with PhD are not just people with better bachelor degrees - PhDs rather are apprenticeships in knowledge generation. Nor are jobs on a single ladder, each job has its particular set different skills it requies. Its not like being a government advisor requires a higher level of competence at the same skills as an IT centre manager. It requires a different set of skills.

Of those that you describe, the job that is closest to being a match for the precise skills a PhD teaches is Professor (although not even then really, as a professors job is far more than research). But there are far more PhD graduates each year than professor jobs. Consider: To maintain a constant number of professors, each professor needs to be replaced by one person when they retire. However, during their career, a professor might graduate 20-30 PhD students. There is no way all of those student can become professors. Luckily professor is a job that only appeals to a subset of people, and not everyone that does a PhD wants to be a professor.

It is important for any student to realize, before they embark of a PhD, that irrespective of how prestigious a school they go to, a PhD cannot guarantee anyone a good job.

Answer (score 6):

Your judgement of the two latter cases is unfair and misinformed. They are only "failures" if they, themselves, consider themselves to be failures. They may feel wildly successful, doing precisely what they want to do. The doctorates may have had less to do with their happiness and sense of personal fulfillment than being active in some way.

It is a bit dangerous to judge other people. You say you know these people. What do they think? What are their objectives? What opportunities or obstacles do they have?

Not everyone feels that academic success is the highest value that life can be judged by. Not everyone has the same opportunities, even with good degrees.

Answer (score 4):

In any reasonably large population of this kind (e.g. PhDs from a particular university)
there will be a large range of outcomes. You have chosen to examine two outliers at each end of a spectrum you have vaguely and arbitrarily defined and called "life success" and asked for an explanation.

The answer is "variation". In that population there are many randomly distributed determinants of "success" (by any definition). Some of those people are smarter than others.  Some are more ambitious. Some are luckier.

Your question really has nothing to do with academia, or doctorates.
I think your underlying misunderstanding is of statistics.